# how to sort odd numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

I have two lists:
one has all of the given numbers
and second has only odd numbers of the first list

for example:

```
def sort_array(array):
    odds = array
    
    for x in range(len(odds)):
        if (odds[x] % 2) != 0:
            odds[x] = None
            
    
    
    #return final list
```

i want to sort (saving index) and then reverse (also saving index) the second list
and final i want to return combined list

Comment: What exactly is your question? You've just listed some requirements without making any real effort to find a solution yourself. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
aa = list(reversed(sorted([x for x in a if x % 2 != 0])))
b = [] 

for num in a:
    b.append([num, a.index(num)])  # b will be a list of tuples "a" with index attached.
```

I don't know what you're really after for your end result, but heres some answers for the things you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to store/manipulate indexes. Use an iterator on the sorted odd values within a comprehension that selects between even items and the next (sorted) odd value:

```
def sortOdds(array):
    odds = reversed(sorted(n for n in array if n%2))
    return [next(odds) if n%2 else n for n in array]

A = [1,3,4,6,5,8,9,7]
R = sortOdds(A)

print(R)

[9, 7, 4, 6, 5, 8, 3, 1]
```